# Как сделать поддомен

Tags: .htaccess, php

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).site.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.site.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page.php
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{HTTP_HOST}$1
RewriteRule ^(.*).site.ru /page.php?id=$1
```

Правила рабочие, все ок. Но возникла проблема сделать поддомен:

```
RewriteRule ^poddomen.site.ru/(.*)/$ /somepage.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Хоть и проставлено правило, но все равно происходит скрипт /page.php?id=$1

Можно ли как то исправить? Просто неохота писать костыль в файле page.php

Answer (score 1):

Последнее правило вконце прописано? Если да, то тогда срабатывает правило

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).site.ru /page.php?id=$1
```

Попробуйте перенести выше.
А по хорошему сервер такими делами должен заниматься